# ¿Como mandar elemento de array a la ultima posición de este en C#?

Tags: c#, array, .net

Tengo por ejemplo un arreglo como:

`int[] arreglo = new int[10] { 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0 };`

y quiero acomodar todos los 0 al lado derecho de mi arreglo, osea poner todos los ceros al final del arreglo y los números mayores a 0 a la izquierda, hay alguna forma de crear la logica sin tener que usar el método de .Sort ?

Answer (score 9):

Una posible opción es usar linq, para seleccionar los elementos que no son 0 y después concatenar los que si lo son:

```
arreglo = arreglo.Where(x => x != 0).Concat(arreglo.Where(x => x == 0)).ToArray();
```

**Edit**

Ya que quieres una opción sin usar Linq, te pongo una sencilla y nada optimizada para ver la lógica:

```
int[] arreglo2 = new int[arreglo.Length];
int contador = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arreglo.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            if (arreglo[j] != 0)
            {
                arreglo2[contador] = arreglo[j];
                contador++;
            }
        }

        if (i == 1)
        {
            if (arreglo[j] == 0)
            {
                arreglo2[contador] = arreglo[j];
                contador++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: me parece una buena solución, pero no hay forma de crear esta lógica de concatenacion sin usar Linq? es lo que realmente me estoy preguntando.

Comment: Si, deberia especificar en la pregunta, aunque puse que sin usar el metodo sort, realmente no queria usar ninguna libreria que me ordene datos pero de no ser asi creo que optaria por usar Linq

Comment: @Jason0495 ¿por qué no usar Linq? Para no recibir respuestas que no desees, considero que deberías especificar aquellas condiciones por las cuales no usar X o Y tecnología, o en su caso, especificar que solamente lo quieres lograr a través de un `for` o un `while` o `foreach` etc...

Comment: @Flxtr  si realmente lo quería lograr con un for/while/foreach sin depender de alguna libreria de ordenamiento, simplemente para aprender la logica de estas librerias.

Comment: @Jason0495 mi hermano, no hay necesidad de reinventar la rueda, si ya hay algo que existe y lo haga, adelante, haz uso de la tecnología que para eso se inventó :D (a menos que lo hagas a modo de aprendizaje, eso es diferente)

Comment: @Flxtr Si, la verdad todo es cosa mía haha, y si esto es a modo de aprendizaje, pero ya con un proyecto en serio sin duda optaria por Linq/sort etc.

Comment: @Jason0495 y Pikoh, mirad a ver si se pueden borrar comentarios obsoletos (y Jason, recuerda marcarla como aceptada si te ha servido). Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Propongo una solución un poco más optimizada para mandar los elementos a la última posición del array sin tener que volver a recorrerlo entero para cada elemento.

En el código voy explicando con comentarios lo que se va haciendo:

```
int[] arreglo = new int[10] { 1, 8, 2, 0, 3, 9, 4, 0, 5, 0 };

// Recorremos el array en busca de ceros
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    // Si encontramos un 0
    if(arreglo[i] == 0)
    {
        // Recorremos el array a partir de la siguiente posición en busca de números 
        // distintos a 0 para intercambiarlos
        int j = i + 1;
        while(j < arreglo.Count())
        {
            // Si el siguiente número es un 0 pasamos a la siguiente posición del array en 
            // busca de otros números distintos de 0
            if (arreglo[j] == 0)
            {
                j++;
            }
            // Si el numero es distinto de 0 los intercambiamos y avanzamos ambas 
            // posiciones en el array, ya que el arreglo[i] será distinto de 0
            else
            {
                int aux = arreglo[i];
                arreglo[i] = arreglo[j];
                arreglo[j] = aux;
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }                     
    }
}
```

Aún más optimizada si nos da igual el orden del resto de números:

```
int[] numeros = new int[]{1,8,2,0,3,9,4,0,5,0};
int index = numeros.Count() - 1;
for (int i = numeros.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (numeros [i] == 0) {
        int aux = numeros[i];
        numeros[i] = numeros[index];
        numeros[index] = aux;
        index--;
    }
}
```