# ¿Como mandar carácteres a la ultima posición de un array en C#?

Tags: c#, array, visual-studio

Me gustaria saber como podria realizar esto, tengo un array de tipo string, por ejemplo:

```
string[] arreglo = new string[] { "A", "B", "1", "N", "R", "D", "N", "H", "3", "5", "M", "N" };
```

Y me gustaria saber como puedo enviar todos los caracteres "N" al final del arreglo, que quedara asi:

```
{"A", "B", "1", "5", "R", "D","M", "H", "3", "N", "N", "N"}
```

Tambien me gustaria saber si se puede hacer esto solo utilizando bucles como `for/while/do-while`

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Puedes implementar algun tipo de comparador, o con un `for` cada vez que detectes una "n" hacer `pop` del array y `push` al final o ir creando un nuevo array.. Intenta algo y muestranos tus problemas o errores siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Lo había intentado con un for que recorra cada posicion y valdiarlo con un if si es "N", despues intercambiar con la ultima posicion del array, pero no se como validar si el siguiente valor ultimo tambien es una "N" por lo que no quedaria como yo esperaria.

Comment: @Jason0495 muestra ese codigo para que sobre él podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hace poco respondí a una pregunta muy muy similar. Creo que echandole un vistazo solucionará tu problema,es [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/144130/15301). Por cierto, ahora que lo veo fue a ti mismo si no me equivoco, y no aceptaste ninguna respuesta

Comment: @Jason0495 _pero no se como validar si el siguiente valor ultimo tambien es una "N"_  esto puedes hacerlo, te explico a modo de pseudocodigo: preguntando si la posición donde moverás el `valor + 1 = "N"` que lo coloque antes de esa posición `tuArreglo[posición -1]` de lo contrario lo coloca en la posición normal.

Comment: Puedes explicar la lógica que deseas que pase ya que el resultado no guarda relación con lo que dices.

Answer (score 0):

Hay bastantes de formas de hacerlo, como me gustan mas las listas que los arrays te muestro una forma "bastante creativa" que se me ha ocurrido:

```
        public static string[] DiscriminarString(string[] sinOrdenar, string caracter)
        {
            int contadorCaracter = 0;
            List<string> ordenado = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in sinOrdenar)
            {
                if (item != caracter)
                    ordenado.Add(item);
                else
                    contadorCaracter++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < contadorCaracter; i++)
            {
                ordenado.Add(caracter);
            }
            return ordenado.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Puesto a ser creativo, yo el ultimo for le sustituiria por algo como `ordenado = ordenado.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(caracter, contadorCaracter)).ToList();` :)

Comment: Más creativo y mas guai xD